ggplot: how to have secondary y axis independent from the first?
I am trying to plot two lines with ggplot. The second line has a different scale and I would like to have a secondary axis for it, which is completely independent from the first.
I have already looked at other answers (like this one), but I understand that ggplot can only handle the secondary axis if it is a rescaling of the first one. I also understand the limitations and caveats of using a secondary axis, as explained in the linked answer. However, I just need to do it this way.
I need to achieve something like the following graph (which is super easy to do in Excel...):

Also, how do I get the legend entries to be stacked in one column? The legend.box = "vertical" does not seem to work as desired.
Here is a minimal working version of my data:
dt <- structure(list(time = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025), y1 = c(2.31631335338909, 
-0.353036222182179, 0.822172487550787, 1.65036005686483, 3.19324989973053, 
1.36886369415437, 1.31791693469558, 0.184416719383496, -1.48872180894084, 
-0.92173552297502, 3.9135578292683, 0.346256544376589, 1.91127730330776, 
0.786333884748602, 1.58411983190534, 1.42796690725975, 1.19061818749784, 
1.86907738573789, 2.20102287412618, 0.74258282086539, 0.558112794652055, 
0.738532378963908, -1.32864718685318, 1.42498210081179, 2.51616000832833, 
1.77839234915598), y2 = c(128.2294422, 124.4007109, 123.4816498, 
122.9197759, 127.1120084, 126.7419716, 126.5872646, 126.038439, 
127.601628, 128.8175759, 135.1116, 132.4616906, 132.6761827, 
132.9141464, 134.0523005, 133.7149933, 133.7150548, 136.17692, 
137.6007351, 135.2282579, 136.9279822, 138.9379415, 140.1117915, 
131.9687439, 134.7674794, 135.7405411)), row.names = c(NA, -26L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

p <-
  ggplot(data = dt,
         aes(x = time)
  ) +
  # Line
  geom_line( data = dt,
             aes( y = y1,
                  colour = "% change"
             )
  ) +
  geom_line( data = dt,
             aes( y = y2,
                  colour = "Index"
             )
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  )


Not sure how you can have the secondary axis completely independent of the first. They must be linked if you want to show them in the same plot area.

Scale the y2 values for the secondary axis, then add it to the plot with sec_axis. Use guides() to alter the legend.
a <- (max(dt$y1) - min(dt$y1))/(max(dt$y2) - min(dt$y2))
b <- max(dt$y1) - a * max(dt$y2)

dt$y2_new <- a * dt$y2 + b
#y = (y2 - b)/a # reverse transformation

ggplot(data = dt,
         aes(x = time)) +
  # Line
  geom_line( data = dt,
             aes( y = y1,
                  colour = "% change")) +
  geom_line( data = dt,
             aes( y = y2_new,
                  colour = "Index")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="% change", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~(. - b)/a, name="Index")) +
  theme(
#    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank()) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=1))



